# Erlang gen_tcp:send binary get merged?

Tags: binary, erlang, gen-tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gen_tcp smushed messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209261/gen-tcp-smushed-messages)

Sometimes when I send binary data with `gen_tcp:send` it gets merged in the inbox, example `<<0,1>>` and `<<1,0>>` will be received as `<<0,1,1,0>>`. How can I fix this? Thanks for replies.